# Apex Test Catch Exception

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

How can i catch this method in apex test class

```
  public static void CountparentRetirementAccountUpdate1(List<Holding__c> holdings){
    List<id> reaccid=new List<id>();
    List<id> fundid=new List<id>();
    for(Holding__c hol : holdings){
        reaccid.add(hol.Retirement_Account__c);
        fundid.add(hol.Fund__c);
    }
    List<Retirement_Account__c> retacclist = [select id,Account_Summary__c,(select id,Amount__c,Fund__r.Category__c from Holdings__r ORDER BY Amount__c DESC,Fund__r.Category__c ASC LIMIT 3) from Retirement_Account__c where id IN: reaccid ];
 try{for(Retirement_Account__c r:retacclist){   
     String category='';   
  for(Holding__c h:r.Holdings__r){  
      String s;           
      if(h.Fund__c!=null && h.Fund__r.Category__c!=null){
          s= h.Fund__r.Category__c;           
      }
      else{
          s='Unknown';
      }
      category += (category==''?'':',')+s;              
       System.debug('ss'+s);
  }          
      r.Account_Summary__c =category;  

   system.debug('#####'+retacclist);     
    } 
     update retacclist; 
     List<Fund__c> fundList=[select id,Total_Shares_Outstanding__c,(select 
  id,Fund__c,Shares__c from Holdings__r) from Fund__c where id IN:fundid];
   for(Fund__c fList:fundList)
    {
        decimal sum=0;           
        for(Holding__c holdList:fList.Holdings__r)
        {
             holdList.Fund__c=fList.Id;
            if(holdList.Shares__c!=null){                   
            sum +=holdList.Shares__c; 
            }
        }
       fList.Total_Shares_Outstanding__c =sum;         

    }
           update fundList;
    }
     catch(Exception e)
    {
        system.debug(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you mean how can you tell that the method caught and debug logged an exception while in a unit test, this is most easily done by doing something like:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug(e);

    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I.e. only when executing a test is the exception re-thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock a `private testVisible` variable in your main class and then set its value in the test class to see if the exception has occurred. The advantage of mocking from `Test.isRunningTest()` is you are in control when an exception is thrown. For some testing method, you don't want this behavior thus you can bypass exception throwing.

```
public with sharing class MyApexClass {


    @TestVisible
    private static boolean enableExceptionThrowing = false;


    public static void CountparentRetirementAccountUpdate1(List<Holding__c> holdings) {
        List<id> reaccid = new List<id>();
        List<id> fundid = new List<id>();
        for (Holding__c hol : holdings) {
            reaccid.add(hol.Retirement_Account__c);
            fundid.add(hol.Fund__c);
        }
        List<Retirement_Account__c> retacclist = [select id,Account_Summary__c, (select id,Amount__c,Fund__r.Category__c from Holdings__r ORDER BY Amount__c DESC, Fund__r.Category__c ASC LIMIT 3) from Retirement_Account__c where id IN:reaccid];
        try {
            for (Retirement_Account__c r : retacclist) {
                String category = '';
                for (Holding__c h : r.Holdings__r) {
                    String s;
                    if (h.Fund__c != null && h.Fund__r.Category__c != null) {
                        s = h.Fund__r.Category__c;
                    } else {
                        s = 'Unknown';
                    }
                    category += (category == '' ? '' : ',') + s;
                    System.debug('ss' + s);
                }
                r.Account_Summary__c = category;

                system.debug('#####' + retacclist);
            }
            update retacclist;
            List<Fund__c> fundList = [
                    select id,Total_Shares_Outstanding__c, (
                            select
                                    id,Fund__c,Shares__c
                            from Holdings__r
                    )
                    from Fund__c
                    where id IN:fundid
            ];
            for (Fund__c fList : fundList) {
                decimal sum = 0;
                for (Holding__c holdList : fList.Holdings__r) {
                    holdList.Fund__c = fList.Id;
                    if (holdList.Shares__c != null) {
                        sum += holdList.Shares__c;
                    }
                }
                fList.Total_Shares_Outstanding__c = sum;

            }
            update fundList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(e);
            if(enableExceptionThrowing)
                throw e;
        }

    }




}
```

Test class:

```
private static void unitTestForException(){

    MyApexClass.enableExceptionThrowing = true ; 

    MyApexClass.CountparentRetirementAccountUpdate1(records); //This should throw exception in your test class



}
```